# Laravel поддомен в route

Tags: laravel

есть сайт site.ru

при переходе по ссылке site.ru/cabinet нужно, чтобы редирект был на

cabinet.site.ru

написал route так

```
Route::domain('{cabinet}.site.ru')->namespace('Cabinet')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/','ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы сделать редирект на поддомен нужно выполнить 2 шага:

```
// Шаг 1 (редирект на поддомен)

Route::get('cabinet', function () {
  return Redirect::to('http://cabinet.site.ru'); // указание протокола обязательно
});

// Шаг 2 (роуты для поддомена, namespace и middleware можно добавить)

Route::domain('{cabinet}.site.ru')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', function($cabinet) {
    dd('Это главная страница поддомена!');
  });
  Route::get('user/{id}', function ($cabinet, $id) {
    dd('Это страница пользователя с id: ' . $id);
  });
 // здесь могут быть другие роуты поддомена
});

Route::get('/', 'PageController@index'); // роут для главной страницы основного сайта должен идти после роутов шага 1 и шага 2.
```